# Bot doesn't send the attachments | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, embed

I am trying to make my bot send the exact message that a user sends to a specific channel (contain the embeds) but the bot sends the text but not the attachments

Here is the code

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.id == "771695635598278677") {
        message.delete()
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        let messageAttachment = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.array()[0].url : null
        const dark = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setDescription(message.content)
        .setAuthor("Dark Chat", `${message.author.displayAvatarURL()}`)
        .setImage((messageAttachment)) //message.attachments.first() || {}).url
        .setFooter('Dark Chat', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/564032243836780558/771614643159433226/Anonymous_emblem.svg.png')
        if(isNaN(message.content)) {
            message.channel.send(dark)
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setImage

```
 .setImage(message.attachments.array().length == 0 ? null:message.attachments.first().url)
```